# Paramiko/sshtunnel - translate ssh -r command with full output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

How to reproduce this command fully:

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run
```

on paramiko or sshtunnel with the full output of that?

PS: (**You can also execute this command yourself and see the result**)

I tried something like this:

```
import paramiko 
from threading import Thread
from rforward import reverse_forward_tunnel
    
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

ssh.connect(username="nokey", hostname="localhost.run")
transport = ssh.get_transport()
    
Thread(target=reverse_forward_tunnel, args=(80, "localhost", 8080, transport))
print(ssh._transport.get_banner())
```

Using https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/rforward.py

I need the last output that looks like:

```
255a9142244f36.lhrtunnel.link tunneled with tls termination, https://255a9142244f36.lhrtunnel.link
```

Comment: It seems that the line comes on a shell output. Because when using `plink` with `-N` switch (*don't start  shell/command*), that line does not come (while the previous output that comes as a banner does). So `ssh.invoke_shell().read(...)` should return it. But I was not able to retrieve it.

Comment: I tried `ssh.invoke_shell().recv(...)` but nothing is output. localhost.run is available to everyone, you can safely enter this command into the terminal and check for yourself

Comment: I did try it! I wrote the same in my comment.